# Getting xpath based on login button from a web link

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to run Selenium using python, and I was successful in starting the browser and entering user name and password, but I was not able to run xpath for login button.

```
     Python Script 
         import selenium
         from selenium import webdriver
         from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
         from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
         from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
         from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
         mydriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Mypath\chromedriver.exe")
         baseurl = "http://www.gcrit.com/build3/admin/"
         mydriver.get(baseurl)
         username = "admin"

     xpaths = { 'usernameTxtBox' : "//input[@name='username']",
       'passwordTxtBox' : "//input[@name='password']",
       'submitButton' :   "//input[@name='login']"
     }      mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['usernameTxtBox']).send_keys(username)
           password = "admin@123"
           mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['passwordTxtBox']).send_keys(password)

    All other steps run fine except this one: 
     mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['loginButton']).click()
```

I am getting this error message

```
      mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['loginButton']).click()
      KeyError: 'loginButton'

       I tried getting the Xpath from element as well but I got the same error. @id="tdb1"]
```

HTML of Login Button (It would be helpful to know any efficient way of identifying elements) :

```
    <button id="tdb1" type="submit" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-primary ui-priority-secondary" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-key"></span><span class="ui-button-text">Login</span></button>
```

Comment: What is `xpaths`?

Comment: If id is available then why you are trying using xpath ? For the login button locate element using id `tdb1` and use `.submit()` method instead of `.click()` to perform the click. Let me know if any issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've defined somewhere dictionary `xpaths` you should check whether it really looks like:

```
xpaths = {'usernameTxtBox': '//input[@name="username"]', 'passwordTxtBox': '//input[@name="password"]', 'loginButton': '//button[@id="tdb1"]'}
```

*Update*

Note that you've defined Submit button with `submitButton` key while trying to get its value with `loginButton` key

Comment: It looks like this: xpaths = { 'usernameTxtBox' : "//input[@name='username']",
           'passwordTxtBox' : "//input[@name='password']",
           'submitButton' :   "//input[@name='login']"
         }

Comment: So `submitButton`, not `loginButton`? That the error

Comment: Awesome ! Worked perfectly, Thank You for your help and time !!

Answer (score 1):

The `KeyError` in python generally occurs when your key is not found. You sure 'loginButton' is in set of existing keys?

From official python libraries,

> exception KeyError
>
> Raised when a mapping (dictionary) key is not found in the set of
>   existing keys.

Please see [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError) link.